# No heat when idle

Tags: hvac, heater

I have a 2013 Dodge Grand Caravan. I had the heater core replaced recently and now I don't have heat on the right front passenger side.

I have flush the line both front and back and ensured the computer is all working properly.  The computer says the doors are opening and shutting properly.

Additionally the coolest levels are fine.

Any ideas what could be happening?

Comment: Heat don't make choices about which side to come out of, it either comes out cold, Luke warm or hot. If it's blowing out hot on one side but not the other, then you have a duct that wasn't fansenced back together properly or the door trap is preventing anything to the other side

Comment: Is there any repair guides to check that?

Comment: If you wanted to check all of the duct work then you need to take apart the dash, but you can see a lot of it just by going upside down and feeling like a contortionist, maybe try and run a snake through the vents or one of those snakes with the cameras on the end, can't think of what their called at the moment

Comment: Endoscope snake, there we go, they even have them where they'll connect to your phone now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If heat is fine on the other side and there's no signs of overheating or other coolant problems I'd be inclined to suggest it's either an airlock or other obstruction in the heater matrix pipework for the passenger side.

You could try opening all vents, setting the heater & fans to maximum and bleeding the coolant system.

Comment: I'll try that tonight

Comment: Seems to have solved it plus I added some cleaner to it.